# Error creating RDS event subscription

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cli, amazon-sns

I am trying to create an **Event Subscription for RDS via AWS CLI**

I have successfully created an **SNS** and can confirm it in AWS Console.
I am also able to create Event Subscription via AWS Console but not through **AWS CLI**

The command that I am running :

```
aws rds create-event-subscription --subscription-name rds-replica-events-subscription --sns-topic-arn arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:XXXXXXXX:RDS-replication-alarms --enabled
```

The error message :

```
An error occurred (SNSInvalidTopic) when calling the CreateEventSubscription operation: Failed to create Subscription because of Topic arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:XXXXXXXX:RDS-replication-alarms ARN Name Invalid.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. I had to add region.

```
aws rds create-event-subscription  --region us-east-2--subscription-name rds-replica-events-subscription --sns-topic-arn arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:XXXXXXXX:RDS-replication-alarms --enabled
```